# Apply a dynamic string to a field before validation

Tags: php, drupal

I am attempting to set the "title" value of a content type before it becomes "required" . 
So what happens is the title field becomes hidden based on user name, after filling in the "first name" and "last name" fields I need to take those values and then apply them to the "title" field, before drupal states that the field is required. Here's what I have so far

```
/**
*  Implements hook_form_alter().
*/

function editorhide_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){ 

global $user;
global $fullTitle;

if($form_id == 'artist_node_form'){     
   if( $user->name == 'Editor'){        

        drupal_add_js("jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#edit-title').hide();
     });","inline");                
            //adding the form handler
    $form['#submit'][] = "editorhide_form_submit_handler";          

     }
}

}

//submit form handler.

function editorhide_form_submit_handler ($form, &$form_state) {

global $fullTitle;
  $fullTitle = $form_state['values']['field_firstname']['und']['0']['value'];
  $fullTitle .= ' '. $form_state['values']['field_lastname']['und']['0']['value'];
  form_set_value($form['#edit-title'], $fullTitle,$form_state);
}
```

With my current implementation, it isn't doing quite what I want, as it's throwing the "required field" error.

Comment: I implemented that same behavior using hook_node_presave and setting the title field at that time. I'd also recommend the drupal contrib name module to store first and last names in a drupal content type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that your new submit function never gets executed.  A form will go through all validation functions first.

You need to set a new validate function, and make sure it is inserted at the begining of the validation process (so you can set title prior to the node validation):

```
array_unshift($form['#validate'], "editorhide_form_validate_handler");
```

Then your validation can do the following (may need to adjust array indexes):

```
function editorhide_form_validate_handler ($form, &$form_state) {

  $fullTitle = $form_state['values']['field_firstname']['und']['0']['value'];   
  $fullTitle .= ' '. $form_state['values']['field_lastname']['und']['0']['value'];
  $form_state['values']['title']['und']['0']['value'] = $fullTitle;
}
```

I am not a HUGE fan of modifying form_state mid validation, but this should work.